# Refactor rails params in controller to check if params present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to refactor this code for more DRY controller?

```
@places = Place
@places = @places.address(params[:address]) if params[:address].present?
@places = @places.address(params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
@places = @places.price_greater_than_equal params[:price_from] if params[:price_from].present?
#and more..
```

method address is build from scope in model
sorry for bad english

Comment: You should include the "#and more": your third condition about the price is totally different to name and address, which are simple comparisons.  Also explain what you want to do, because having people guess what you want to do by looking at your code is problematic when your code is full of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using the Rails Way ? if params are present they will be updated. the validations should be in the model in necessary.

```
 def update
    @places.update(places_params)
    respond_with(@places)
  end

private
def set_places
  @places = Places.find(params[:id])
end

def places_params
  params.require(:places_params).permit(:address, :postcode, address_attributes: :address (nested attributes)) 
end
```